# how to get access token from Instagram using password and username?

Tags: flutter, instagram-graph-api

I'm trying to get access token from Instagram API using username and password
but in Instagram Graph API requires app ID for connected Instagram account with Facebook

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api

I need to make it dynamically with any account username and password not specific account

Answer (score 0):

Citing the website you linked:

> ### Limitations
>
> The API cannot access Instagram consumer accounts (i.e., non-Business or non-Creator Instagram accounts). If you are building an app for consumer users, use the [Instagram Basic Display API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api) instead.

The Instagram Basic Display API has:

> ### Common Uses
>
> - Get an Instagram User Access Token and permissions from an Instagram user

Comment: Is basic display API gives me the info about the user followers using the access token